# "case sequence" in python implemented with dictionaries

Tags: c++, python

i have implemented a function:

```
def postback(i,user,tval):
    """functie ce posteaza raspunsul bazei de date;stringul din mesaj tb sa fie mai mic de 140 de caractere"""
    result = {
        1:api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Trebuie sa-mi spui si marca pe care o cauti'),
        2:postmarket(user,tval),
        3:api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Imi pare rau, dar nu stiu unde poti gasi aceste tipuri de smantana: %s' % tval)}
    return result.get(i)
```

but it does not work as a case alternative(from c++) it executes all 3 cases no matter wha i try...i'm a begginer so there might be another error, so please help!p.s. please don't tell me that the if...else.. is the only alternative cause i know this can work

Comment: Why not use `if i==1: ...; elif i==2: ...; elif i==3: ...`?  What's wrong with `if`?

Comment: it's too old; and destroys the beauty of the code, in my opinion

Comment: If your code doesn't work, what "beauty" does it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It executes all three cases because you define the `result` dict that way! You call all three functions and assign them to the keys 1, 2, 3.

What you should instead is something like this:

```
functions = {
    1: lambda: api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Trebuie sa-mi spui si marca pe care o cauti'),
    2: lambda: postmarket(user,tval),
    3: lambda: api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Imi pare rau, dar nu stiu unde poti gasi aceste tipuri de smantana: %s' % tval)}
func = functions.get(i)
if func:
    return func()
else:
    raise ValueError("Bad index: %d!" % i)
```

Here I define small wrapper functions and store those in the dict instead. You then pick the right function and call on this one function.

Comment: You could even refactor the function call to `return functions.get(i, lambda:raise ValueError("Bad index: %d!" % i))()` to avoid the following branch.

Comment: Rudi: yeah, that would work too. I have a slight preference for the explicit if-statement, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must use a dict, use a dict of functions:

```
result = {
    1: lambda: api.PostDirectMessage(...),
    2: lambda: postmarket(...),
    ...
}
return result[i]()
```

The `lambda` keyword defines an anonymous inline function, and they only get called on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The value expressions in the dict will be evaluated when this is compiled. If you want those things executed, you could wrap them in a lambda.

```
def postback(i,user,tval):
    result = {
        1: lambda: api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Trebuie sa-mi spui si marca pe care o cauti'),
        2: lambda: postmarket(user,tval),
        3: lambda: api.PostDirectMessage(user,'Imi pare rau, dar nu stiu unde poti gasi aceste tipuri de smantana: %s' % tval)}
    return result.get(i)
```